# compressed CHAR vs Integer performance?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using MySQL 5.5. This question is not bound to specific query, but to the whole idea of select optimization of compressed CHAR and INT. I am just curious...

I am trying to determine whether integer will perform better than "compressed"(or hashed) characters.

For example, I could compress an integer with X base character(maybe UTF-8 hashed). If done right, I could compress 3 byte integer to one character.

In the case of 3 byte integer(-8388607~8388607) and compressed(length=1) character and both indexed, would the select statement with compressed character performance increase?

Comment: What is the query you have in mind?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually, I am just curious if performance would increase for most select statements. To my logic, searching for one character would be less work than searching for 10000000(I am not a MySQL expert, so my logic may be wrong).

Comment: @GordonLinoff However, my actual use case was simple addressbook that has tables like "user","phonelist". I needed to find a way to search for mutual friends via phone numbers. ("select * from user where userNum having (mutual friend table)" was basic idea of my query)

Comment: You should store phone numbers as character strings and set up a rational database structure.  When things work, then you can think about how to optimize storage formats (which probably will not be necessary).

Comment: is it in human nature to ask complex questions what doesn't sound logical? you DON'T want to compress UTF8 data because it cant be compressed savely this idea sounds an bit like premature optimisation to me.. if you want to compress UTF8 use zlib without thinking of making your own way.. or use InnoDB engine compression out off the box... basically an INT datatype field will be faster then an CHAR datatype  field most of the time with indexing.

Comment: also - i would think that a 64 bit system would perform multibyte integer comparisons faster than you could uncompress the values later.